# Pivot Table Excel 2016 - 2019

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have the data below :
[image]

What i want to do is to get the numbers of faults opened /closed  each monthes to get something like this

[image]

Comment: Use COUNTIF or COUNTIFS.

Comment: in pivot table ?

Comment: No, in just a regular table.

Comment: i can't see how only countifs can be the answer, i have to regroup the number per month

Comment: As an example for May: count the open dates that are `>=DATE(2019,5,1)` and `<DATE(2019,6,1)`, or maybe `<=DATE(2019,5,31)`... EOMONTH might be useful too.

Comment: ok, but i am searching a solution with pivot table